# Scala coding standards: curly braces on the same line

Tags: scala

The [scala coding standards](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/nested-blocks.html#curly-braces) state that

> Technically, Scala’s parser does support GNU-style notation with opening braces on the line following the declaration. However, the parser is not terribly predictable when dealing with this style due to the way in which semi-colon inference is implemented. Many headaches will be saved by simply following the curly brace convention demonstrated above.

I've looked, and I couldn't find any real examples of this. Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this with an exmaple? Has anyone run into problems with using curly braces on a new line?

Comment: I added some further explanation to my answer to clarify where ambiguities can arise. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. I've accepted your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this expression:

```
someElement
{
   // Some code
}
```

How is this interpreted? Is it an expression (such as a value, or a function call with no arguments) followed by a block statement enclosed within braces? Or is it a function call with the braces enclosing a single argument?

If *Scala* didn't have semicolon inference—that is, if *Scala* required semicolons to denote the end of a statement in the same manner that *Java* does—then the two could be easily distinguished because the former would require a semicolon at the end of the first line. However, the *Scala* parser has to *infer* where the semicolon(s) need to be to make sense of the code, and sometimes it gets things wrong. (Both interpretations, depending upon context, are valid and it's not always possible for the *Scala* parser to resolve the ambiguity by itself.)

For example, let's say that `someElement` is a function with a *by name* argument. If you attempt to call it in the *Scala REPL* intending to put the argument (within braces) on another line, you'll find that entering `someElement` alone causes an error:

```
> scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def someElement(x: => Int): Int = {
     |   // Do something...
     |   x
     | }
someElement: (x: => Int)Int

scala> someElement
<console>:13: error: missing argument list for method someElement
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `someElement _` or `someElement(_)` instead of `someElement`.
       someElement
       ^
```

That is, you don't even get as far as entering the braces. However, if you enter the following, then you're OK:

```
scala> someElement {
     |   10
     | }
res0: Int = 10
```

But what if `someElement` is a value? Now we see this in the *REPL*:

```
scala> val someElement = 5
someElement: Int = 5

scala> someElement
res1: Int = 5

scala> {
     |   5
     | }
res2: Int = 5
```

Now the *REPL* accepts the same code, on separate lines, as two different expressions.

Let's get really ambiguous. Say `someElement` is a value, but it's now a reference to a function taking a single argument. Let's look at the possible interpretations:

```
scala> def square(a: Int) = a * a
square: (a: Int)Int

scala> val someElement = square _
someElement: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1034/1609754699@74abbb

scala> someElement
res3: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1034/1609754699@74abbb

scala> {
     |   5
     | }
res4: Int = 5
```

That is, it's treated as two separate statements: a value followed by a block statement. However:

```
scala> someElement {
     |   5
     | }
res5: Int = 25
```

is treated as a call to `square` with an argument of 5.

The *Scala* compiler is a little smarter than the *REPL* since it can see all of the code at once, and will try to resolve ambiguities by seeing which of the alternatives make the most sense, but its interpretation may not always match yours.

So, as you can see, putting the open brace on the same line—if the two expressions are linked—makes the relationship explicit and removes ambiguity. Alternatively, if you *want* the expressions to be parsed unambiguously as separate statements, add a semicolon after the first line.

(IMHO, the semicolon inference is one of *Scala*'s *Achilles Heels*.)

Comment: FWIW, you can avoid the REPL yelling at you in the first example by entering paste mode:

    scala> :paste
    // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
    
    someElement
    {
      5
    }
    [press Ctrl+D]
    // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
    
    res19: Int = 5

Comment: @CPS Agreed. But the REPL - without paste mode - demonstrates this issue more severely than the compiler, which was my point.